# controlling 8**3 rgb led cube by computer

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I am now in process of creating led cube that should be controlled by arduino bud ewery arduino i know does not have large enough memory to do all functions I want (it would be capable only of algorytmical or little programs) So I am trying to process all date in my computer by `Python` and send it to arduino ewerything works just fine except when I make delay between `serial writes` smaller than `1 second` cube should be `10 Hz` to make some cool animations but `5 Hz` would be good enough, but with my code I am only capable of `1 Hz`

**python:**

```
import serial
import time

arduinoData = serial.Serial('com3', 9600)

time.sleep(2)

while 1:
    arduinoData.write(b'81')
    time.sleep(1)
    arduinoData.write(b'80')
    time.sleep(1)
```

**arduino:**

```
String serialData;
int data;
int pin, value

void setup() {
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() {

  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    serialData = Serial.readString();
    pin = serialData.substring(0, 1).toInt();
    value = serialData.substring(1, 2).toInt();
    digitalWrite(pin, value);
  }
}
```

I want to read/send data throgh serial port faster

**Note:** I am testing it with 2 regural leds

Comment: Your arduino and python must pen a port at the same baudrate (currently you have 9600 in python and 250000 in arduino, this won;t work). Then remove the sleeps from your python code and control the timing with the arduino. you can put a delay of 100ms inside your loop, so it will be executed at a frequency of 10Hz. But if you want to control several rgb leds I suggest using neopixels, so you only need 1 pin to control all leds

Comment: I have put delay just behind void loop(){ and deleted sleeps inside python loop and it doesent work. btw I am using neopixels but I am learning with serial ports on simpler level

Comment: sorry I have same baud rate I just missed it in example

Comment: have you tried `time.sleep(0.1)`?

Comment: yeah, I tried it too, minimum supported time is about 0.994

Answer (score 0):

In the Arduino code, you are using [Serial.readString()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstring/) which reads from the buffer during a preset timeout (default is 1000ms). See [Serial.setTimeout()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/settimeout/) for more informations.

I recommend you to use something like this instead :

```cpp
void loop()
{
    string data = "";
    while(Serial.available()) // Read the buffer until it's empty
    {
        data += Serial.read();
    }
    if(data.length()>0) // Process the data then
    {
        pin = data[0].toInt();
        value = data[1].toInt();
    }
}
```

I suggest you to always refer to the [Arduino documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/).